# Compare 2 lists in excel using Excel or VBA

Tags: excel, vlookup, lookup

First of all, I would like to thank you for taking the time to read this and helping me.
My Excel skills are basic at best, with no knowledge of VBA other than finding the VB Editor.

What I'm trying to do:

Attached is the file I'm working with, to give you a better idea.

[image]

I have 2 Lists (in 2 different sheets, but I combined them to simplify the explanation)

So I tried a few methods and this is the closest one in my opinion but it isn't working correctly.

What i need to use a formula and drag it down (or VBA Macro if easier)
to tell me which row in List 2 matches List 1.

For example,
in List 2, Rows 3 and 5 are matching (so that should say "YES" in Column G)

The first formula i used is

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2,A:A,0)*(E2,B:B)),"YES","NO")
```

Other method I have attempted is use 2 additional columns with (not in the screenshot)

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2,A:A,0)),"YES","NO") 
and 
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(E2,A:A,0)),"YES","NO")
```

But the problem with the second method is that it doesn't work

because I need only "YES" if both values on the same row (in list 2) match with both values on the same row (in List 1).

Comment: Do you need VBA to put in the value? it sounds like a simple excel formula `=IF(AND(A1=C1,B1=D1),"YES","NO")`

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS`.

Comment: @Toddleson the problem with this formula is that the 2 lists don't have all the values on the same row, they can be few rows down. 
I doesn't have to be VBA, just whatever gets the job done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS` and check if the result is `>0`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,D2,B:B,E2)>0,"YES","NO")
```